# Android - exact mathematical calculation

Tags: java, android

I have got a Problem, I am developing an Application which should be able to do some mathematic calculations. These calculations have to be exact (or rather not obviously wrong)

But this simple Code

```
double a = 3.048d;
double b = 1000d;

double c = a / b;
```

gives me a wrong result c is not 0.003048 as expected instead it is 0.0030480000000000004 which is obviously wrong.

```
double d = 3.048 / 1000;
```

this second code-snipet gives the correct result.

I am aware that all floatingpoint arithmetic is not exact when calculating with computers but I don't know how to solve this problem.

thanks in advance!
Ludwig

Developing for:
- Android 2.2
Testdevice:
- HTC Desire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to use for exact percision is the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) object:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("3.048");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(1000);

BigDecimal c = a.divide(b);

System.out.println(c); //0.003048
```

Comment: hey johncarl,
thank you very much for the impicit hint with the String for creating a new BigDecimal I think this could be the problem I had in former times with using BigDecimal.

Comment: I dont know what problem in former times you are referring to, but you could also represent 3.048 as:  BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(3048).divide(new BigDecimal(1000))

Answer (score 1):

Use a [BigDecimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for precise floating point calculations. Setting the scale allows you to specify precisely how far out you want to go for output.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class Test{

        public static void main(String[] args){
                BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("3.048");
                BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(1000);
                BigDecimal c = a.divide(b).setScale(6);
                System.out.println(c); //0.003048
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of the [IEEE 754 floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), not an error. To deal with it, round your result to an appropriate precision.

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal for such *precise* allocations.

Btw the result for d is obviously right, because double has a machine encoding which cannot store the result, which you perceive as correct.